# WPF canvas with relative position

Tags: wpf, canvas, wpfdatagrid

I have this `DataGrid` and this `Canvas`:

```
<DataGrid Canvas.ZIndex="1" x:Name="dgTimeline"/>

<Canvas Height="30" Width="999" Canvas.ZIndex="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="71,387,0,0">
    <Line Name="time" X1="0" Y1="0" X2="0" Y2="24" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2"/>
</Canvas>
```

Which results in:
[image]

However, when I move the horizontal scroll bar of the `DataGrid` the `Canvas` obviously stays on its position because its parent is the `Window` and not the `DataGrid`:[image]

Is it possible to keep `Canvas`' position relative to the `DataGrid` instead of its parent in such a way that when scrolling the `DataGrid` the `Canvas` would stay stationary as it was a `DataGrid`'s element? I tried to put the `Canvas` inside of the `DataGrid` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add horizontal scrollbar to canvas and then try to synchronize the horizontal scrolls of canvas and datagrid. something like ...

```
private void dataGrid_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    canvasScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(e.HorizontalOffset);
}

private void canvasScrollViewer_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ScrollViewer dgScrollViewer = GetScrollViewerInstance();
    dgScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(e.HorizontalOffset);
}

private ScrollViewer GetScrollViewerInstance()
{
    var ctrl = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dataGrid, 0);
    if (ctrl is Border)
    {
        var ctrl1 = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(ctrl, 0);
        if (ctrl1 is ScrollViewer)
        {
            dgScrollViewer = ctrl1 as ScrollViewer;
        }
    }
}
```

This code is just to give you an idea of how to do it and not a actual working code. You set the HorizontalScrollBarVisibility for Canvas to Hidden if you don't want to show it. You will not need the second event handler in that case.